# PIN Transalation error on TermApp Postillion when isuing DUKPT key managemt

Tags: pos, iso8583, dukpt

I am using DUKPT to encrypt PIN for sending iso8385 Messages from a POS terminal to TermApp Postillion
I am sure I am implementing the algorithm correctly and that I am sending the right KSN but I am getting this error from TermApp.

```
A PIN Translation failure occurred for terminal TEST0001 because 
Postilion exception: [postilion.realtime.sdk.crypto.XInvalidPinBlock]
Description: A cryptographic operation (translate DUKPT PIN with derived IPEK) involving key 'KEYSET_FFFFFF_BDK' failed, because invalid data was supplied. The invalid data was in field 'PIN block'. The data was invalid because PIN block invalid according to format NONE.
```

Any help from anyone who has worked with postillion will be appreciated.

Comment: Most probably it's a misalignment between the key used in the terminal and the key in the server, but the question is too vague to give a specific answer. You need to debug your issue with the server administration.

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz I'm sure we are using the same key.  We have been trying to debug the issue with the administartion but we haven't made any progress.

Comment: It seems they have no much experience with the application. The server is failing on pin translation, but the keysetId is successfully locating the BDK. I was thinking that its some configuration error on the App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. It seems I hadn't got information aboutthe pin block format. TermAppIso was configured to use the ISO-0 format on the pinblock,,